# creating deadlock for distributed database in mysql-(Testing purpose)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, trigger, mysql-5.1

I need to create a deadlock  for distributed database in MySQL for testing purpose with a simple sql query(without front end), can anyone good with MySQL query help me out in this with sample query. code can be with stored procedure, trigger or with MySQL query will be helpful.

Regards,

ACUBE.

Comment: By definition, you cannot suffer from an InnoDB deadlock with only one session. You need at least 2. Check some simple example: http://www.slideshare.net/lionpeal/intro-to-deadlocks/7

Comment: Also this blog post: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/08/how-to-deliberately-cause-a-deadlock-in-mysql/

Comment: how to run it parallel,